# Info needed on gradle release plugin as how maven provides release plugin

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gradle, build.gradle

Can any one let me know if there is any release plugin provided by gradle to do similar tasks performed as Maven release plugin do? I know we can load the maven tasks in gradle but do not want to do it and keep things clean if there is any inbuilt plugin provided by gradle. If there is one please please post sample config or code. Thanks in advance.

In maven we have the following tasks performed by maven release plugin:

```
release:clean Clean up after a release preparation.
release:prepare Prepare for a release in SCM.
release:prepare-with-pom Prepare for a release in SCM, and generate release POMs that record the fully resolved projects used.
release:rollback Rollback a previous release.
release:perform Perform a release from SCM.
release:stage Perform a release from SCM into a staging folder/repository.
release:branch Create a branch of the current project with all versions updated.
release:update-versions Update the versions in the POM(s).
```

Thanks
Nithin

Answer (score 2):

Right there are so many choices. I tested most of the release plugins and wrote couple of them for different clients on my own. I really recommend the nebula-release plugin (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.nebula-release). This is driven by the netflix guys, well documented, well maintained and supports all kind of use cases and customizations.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using mentioned townsfolk's release plugin, but it is not actively developed anymore with a few open issues (**update**: It seems that Daniel Tschinder took over development of that plugin, so probably there will be newer versions).

Recently I have found [Axion](https://github.com/allegro/axion-release-plugin) release plugin which doesn't use separate file to keep current version, but uses Git commits and tags to determine it. It simplifies releasing process and fits in Continuous Delivery trend. What is also very important the author is very responsible.

In addition to the README file nice description can be found on their [blog](http://allegro.tech/2014/09/axion-release-plugin.html).

Axion itself do only versioning tests from your list, but it can be used together with maven-publish, bintray or any other publishing plugin to push artifacts into remote artifacts repository.

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth, I have recently published a gradle-release-plugin of my own (https://github.com/anshulverma/gradle-release-plugin).

It works on convention rather than configuration. Which is why I built it in the first place. *Most* of the time we all want the same thing -- semantic versioning with ability to snapshot and tag commits along with publish ability to OSS and bintray repositories. This is what this plugin provides and takes care of most of the configuration.

It is in active development at the moment. Feel free to open issues if any advancements come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there are 4 release plugins right now.

- https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-release
- https://github.com/ari/gradle-release-plugin
- https://github.com/stianh/gradle-release-plugin
- https://github.com/anshulverma/gradle-release-plugin

The townsfolk plugin is the one that works the most like the maven plugin and it works quite well so far ... but is currently not maintained (see github). The other 2 plugins work much differently from the maven release plugin (and pretty similarly to each other). These other two plugins use version control (svn/git) to keep track of version numbers instead of burying (and updating) version numbers in the build.gradle file.

You can also find various approaches here: https://bitbucket.org/evgenyg/demo-releases-plugin/src/master/build.gradle
And some nice slides here: http://www.slideshare.net/evgenyg/release-it

Hope this helps!